# Count first n elements per row of matrix within a desired range

Tags: r, sapply

I wish to count the number of times an element within a desired range appears in each row of a `matrix` with the added condition that I only want to consider the first *n* such elements per row.

A similar question, without the added condition, appears here:

[counting N occurrences within a ceiling range of a matrix by-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862714/counting-n-occurrences-within-a-ceiling-range-of-a-matrix-by-row)

I have written `R` code to do what I want, but it uses nested `for-loops`.  I have also replaced the nested `for-loops` with `sapply` statements, but they also appear inefficient.

I am hoping someone might suggest a more efficient approach ideally in base `R`.  I provide an example data set, my desired output and functional annotated `R` code below.

Here is an example data set.  My actual data sets will be much larger and I will have an enormous number of them.  So, efficiency is important.

```
my.data  <-  matrix( c(0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      74, 22, 12, 13, 56,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      88, 77,  5, 77, 34, 98,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      92,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      89,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      86, 72, 64, 40, 75, 58, 28, 66, 13, 98,
                      18,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                       0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      70, 51, 83, 13, 50, 30,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                       0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      28, 54, 43, 86, 50,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      45, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      39, 57, 58, 90, 84, 47, 36,  0,  0,  0,
                      76, 14, 71, 29,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      23,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                       7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      77, 58, 90, 91, 47, 40, 58, 89,  0,  0,
                      89, 90,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      83, 34, 61,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      17,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      10, 42,  5, 87, 61,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      90, 39, 99, 10, 84, 90, 93, 96, 69,  0,
                      84, 40, 44, 82,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                       0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0),
nrow = 25, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
```

Here are my desired results.  I read each row from left-to-right and 0's are ignored.

```
# These are the number of elements per row that satisfy all conditions
desired.n.kept      <- c(0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0)

# These are the number of elements per row that do not satisfy all conditions 
# up through the specified limit on number of elements that do satisfy all conditions
desired.n.discarded <- c(0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 6, 0, 0)
```

Here I explain several example rows.

In the first row there are no elements that satisfy all conditions.  In other words there are no elements that are `>= 30 & <= 85`.  There are also no elements that do not satisfy all conditions, `< 30 | > 85` keeping in mind that 0's are ignored.  So, `< 30 | > 85` might better be thought of as: `(> 0 & < 30) | > 85`.

In the third row three elements are within the desired range.  These are the second, fourth and fifth elements, the two `77`'s and the `34` because they are `>= 30 & <= 85`.  Two elements (the `88` and the `5`) are outside the desired range [`(> 0 & < 30) | > 85`] to the left of the third element that is within the desired range, i.e., to the left of the fifth element, the `34`.  The sixth element, the `98`, occurs after the limit of 3 kept elements has been reached, i.e., after the two `77`'s and the `34`.  So, the sixth element, the `98`, is ignored.

In the sixth row three elements satisfy all conditions: the `72`, `64` and `40`.  These three elements are the first three to fall within the desired range: `>= 30 & <= 85`.  One element, the `86`, does not satisfy all conditions (it is `> 85`) up through the third element that is kept, i.e., up through the `40`.  Because the `40` is the third element to fall within the desired range (`>= 30 & <= 85`) all six elements to the right of the `40` are ignored regardless of whether they fall within or outside the desired range (the `75`, `58`, `28`, `66`, `13`, and `98` are ignored).

Here is my initial code using nested `for-loops`:

```
# specify the desired range for individual elements
my.min   <- 30
my.max   <- 85

# specify maximum number of elements to keep within desired range per row
my.limit <- 3

my.cols  <- ncol(my.data)
my.rows  <- nrow(my.data)

# indicator matrix identifies elements inside the desired range
in.range <- matrix(0, nrow = my.rows, ncol = my.cols)
in.range[my.data >= my.min & my.data <= my.max] <- 1

# indicator matrix identifies elements outside the desired range
outside.range <- matrix(0, nrow = my.rows, ncol = my.cols)
outside.range[my.data > 0 & (my.data < my.min | my.data > my.max)] <- 1

# count elements that are within the desired range
count.in.range <- t(apply(in.range, 1, cumsum))

# truncate rows after my limit is reached
truncate.rows <- matrix(1, nrow = my.rows, ncol = my.cols)
for(i in 1:my.rows) {
     for(j in 2:my.cols) {
          if((count.in.range[i,(j-1)] >= my.limit) & (count.in.range[i,j] >= my.limit)) {truncate.rows[i,j] = 0}
     }
}

# count the number of elements per row that satisfy all conditions
n.kept <- rowSums(truncate.rows * in.range)
# count the number of elements per row that do not satisfy all conditions
n.discarded <- rowSums(truncate.rows * outside.range)

# verify that my code returns the desired results
all.equal(n.kept, desired.n.kept)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(n.discarded, desired.n.discarded)
#[1] TRUE
```

Here is the `sapply` function I wrote in place of nested `for-loops`.  It does work but you can see it appears overly complex:

```
# This sapply approach returns a matrix with only 9 columns and many NULL elements
truncate.rows2 <- matrix(1, nrow = my.rows, ncol = my.cols)
truncate.rows2 <- t(sapply(1:my.rows, function (i) {
                       sapply(2:my.cols, function(j) {  
                            if((count.in.range[i,(j-1)] >= my.limit) & (count.in.range[i,j] >= my.limit)) {truncate.rows2[i,j] = 0}
                       })
                  }))
truncate.rows2

# modify truncate.rows2 to eliminate NULL elements and restore the first column
truncate.rows3 <- matrix(as.numeric(as.character(truncate.rows2)), ncol = (my.cols-1), nrow = my.rows)
truncate.rows3[is.na(truncate.rows3)] <- 1
truncate.rows3 <- cbind(truncate.rows[,1], truncate.rows3)
truncate.rows3

all.equal(truncate.rows, truncate.rows3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I really don't understand your examples. Can you make your examples based on numbers (instead of 6th element, 3rd element) and avoid duplicated numbers? Maybe that makes understanding this easier.

Comment: I will edit to add the numeric values of elements in the three examples.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the nested for-loop with the following code:

```
# determine last element to keep by row
last.one <- apply(count.in.range, 1, function(x) min(which(x == 3), na.rm = TRUE))
last.one[is.infinite(last.one)] <- 10

# identity matrix of elements to keep
truncate.rows <- matrix(0, nrow = my.rows, ncol = my.cols)
sapply(1:my.rows, function(x) truncate.rows[x,1:last.one[x]] <<- 1)
```

So, the complete functional code becomes:

```
my.data  <-  matrix( c(0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      74, 22, 12, 13, 56,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      88, 77,  5, 77, 34, 98,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      92,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      89,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      86, 72, 64, 40, 75, 58, 28, 66, 13, 98,
                      18,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                       0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      70, 51, 83, 13, 50, 30,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                       0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      28, 54, 43, 86, 50,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      45, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      39, 57, 58, 90, 84, 47, 36,  0,  0,  0,
                      76, 14, 71, 29,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      23,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                       7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      77, 58, 90, 91, 47, 40, 58, 89,  0,  0,
                      89, 90,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      83, 34, 61,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      17,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      62,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      10, 42,  5, 87, 61,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                      90, 39, 99, 10, 84, 90, 93, 96, 69,  0,
                      84, 40, 44, 82,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
                       0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0),
nrow = 25, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)

desired.n.kept      <- c(0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0)
desired.n.discarded <- c(0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 6, 0, 0)

# specify desired range for individual elements
my.min   <- 30
my.max   <- 85

# specify maximum number of elements to keep within desired range per row
my.limit <- 3

my.cols  <- ncol(my.data)
my.rows  <- nrow(my.data)

# indicator matrix identifies elements inside the desired range
in.range <- matrix(0, nrow = my.rows, ncol = my.cols)
in.range[my.data >= my.min & my.data <= my.max] <- 1

# indicator matrix identifies elements outside the desired range
outside.range <- matrix(0, nrow = my.rows, ncol = my.cols)
outside.range[my.data > 0 & (my.data < my.min | my.data > my.max)] <- 1

# count elements that are within the desired range
count.in.range <- t(apply(in.range, 1, cumsum))

# determine last element to keep by row
last.one <- apply(count.in.range, 1, function(x) min(which(x == 3), na.rm = TRUE))
last.one[is.infinite(last.one)] <- 10

# identity matrix of elements to keep
truncate.rows <- matrix(0, nrow = my.rows, ncol = my.cols)
sapply(1:my.rows, function(x) truncate.rows[x,1:last.one[x]] <<- 1)

# count the number of elements per row that satisfy all conditions
n.kept <- rowSums(truncate.rows * in.range)
# count the number of elements per row that do not satisfy all conditions
n.discarded <- rowSums(truncate.rows * outside.range)

# verify that my code returns the desired results
all.equal(n.kept, desired.n.kept)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(n.discarded, desired.n.discarded)
#[1] TRUE
```